Block Matrix Inverse and Imaginary Number
I came here to ask some help regarding the following question.

Let $M \in \mathbb R^{n \times n}$ be a "symmetric" and positive semidefinite matrix, and $M^{(n)}$ is obtained from $M$ by zeroing all elements in the $n$th row and column except on the diagonal. The $M$ and $M^{(n)}$ can be written as $$M = \begin{bmatrix}R & w \\ w^T & u\end{bmatrix}, \quad M^{(n)} =  \begin{bmatrix}R & 0_{n-1} \\ 0_{n-1}^T & u\end{bmatrix},$$ where $R \in \mathbb R^{n-1 \times n-1}$, $w\in\mathbb R^{n-1}$, and $u=M_{n,n}$. For $z\in\mathbb C$, the matrix $(M^{(n)} -zI)^{-1}$ can be written as $$(M^{(n)} -zI)^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}R^{(n)}  & 0_{n-1} \\ 0_{n-1}^T & \rho^{(n)}  \end{bmatrix},$$ where $$R^{(n)}  := (R-zI)^{-1},\qquad \rho^{(n)}  := \frac{1}{u-z}.$$ So, when $\text{Im}(z) \ge a$ for some $a>0$, we have $$\text{Im}(w^TR^{(n)} w) \ge 0,\\ \text{Im}(u-z-w^TR^{(n)} w) \le -a.$$

Everything is quite straightforward, except for the last two terms. $z\in\mathbb C$ is included, so $R^{(n)}$ cannot be positive definite $\because$ not Hermitian matrix.  Then, I'm not sure what information I should use to yield $\text{Im}(w^TR^{(n)}w) \ge 0.$ and how to associate it with the last inequality. So, I'm stuck to this point.
Any comments regarding this question would be grateful. Thank you.

positive semi-definite has conflicting definitions when working over reals -- your block matrix hints that $M$ is symmetric but if true this needs explicitly stated.  Assuming $M$ is symmetric then you can prove the first inequality $\text{Im}(w^TR^{(n)} w) \ge 0$ by using the fact that $R^{(n)}$ is diagonalizabile by a real orthogonal matrix thus reducing the problem to working on a diagonal matrix which necessarily has eigenvalues with positive imaginary components-- i.e. this is a minor variation on the standard quadratic form argument for real symmetric matrices.

Ah, thank you, now I see the meaning of the inequality by using the orthogonal matrix.
